# Not able to retrieve web data using socket programming in python

Tags: python, html, sockets, http, server

Not able to retrieve web data using socket programming in python:

```py
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org',80))

cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(100)
    if(len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')
mysock.close()
```

*Error*

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Date: Sat, 02 Nov 2019 08:41:58 GMT

Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Content-Length: 308

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Via: HTTP/1.1 forward.http.proxy:3128

Connection: close

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at do1.dr-chuck.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid HTTP/1.1 request. It misses the Host header and there should only be a relative path given and not the absolute one:

```
  cmd = 'GET /intro-short.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: data.pr4e.org\r\n\r\n'.encode()
```

For more information please read the [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) and don't just guess how HTTP looks like. Note that HTTP is likely way more complex than you imagine. For example: even with the proper request this program will hang after it got the response.